# How effective is creating index on column having two types of values only

Tags: oracle, query-performance, database-indexes

I have created an index on a column, which has only two possible values (Y and N), data type is same for both values.

Suppose column name is indicator.
I wrote a select statement like,

```
SELECT INDICATOR 
FROM TEMP_TABLE 
ORDER BY INDICATOR
```

When I used explain plan for this query in SQL developer, it is using full table scan not index scan.

Why it is not using index table scan.

Comment: Those are two values; they have the same type. You don’t have two types of values.

Comment: Values are of same data type, but two distinct values Y and N.

Comment: How many rows does the table have?

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the `create table`, the `create index` and the execution plan. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to find a record in a table without an index, the DBMS needs to read all the records to find a match. With an index, the DBMS should only need to read a set of consecutive records to find the matches then go find the corresponding records in the table. So there's an extra step when the DBMS uses an index.

As a rough rule of thumb, if you are reading more than 5% of the records from a table, then a full table scan will be faster than an indexed lookup.

But the distribution of the data is also important. Consider the case where 99% of the data is 'Y'. Using the index to resolve records with 'Y' will be very innefficient (applying the inverse of my rule of thumb, it will take 20 times longer than a full table scan). OTOH using the index to find records with 'N' will be 5 times more efficient than a full table scan.

This is the reason that Oracle uses histograms for more complex index attributes.

Oracle also has a feature called bind peeking - which leverages the distribution issue to choose the most efficient query based on the predicates being searched for. Take some time to think about what happens when the pattern of queries matches the pattern of data - the cached plan will depend on which version of the query is first processed.

Short version: don't use indexes on (a set of) attributes with very low cardinality.

Comment: I disagree. Suppose, as in your example, that 99% of the data is 'Y'. If there are many queries (or few queries that are run frequently) that select the rows with the 'N' flag, then the index makes perfect sense.

Comment: Also - I just realized that the OP was reading ONLY the indexed column. It this case the database should read ONLY the index, it never needs to read ANYTHING from the base table. So I deleted my answer (which was similar to yours except what I pointed out in the above Comment), since it doesn't apply to the OP's specific question.

Answer (score 1):

An index - at least in Oracle, I don't know about other databases - does not store NULL form the underlying column. Since you are asking to read ALL the values from the column, Oracle needs to read them from the base table (even though you are only reading the indexed column - an OBVIOUS case when the index should be used regardless of cardinality estimates and other factors).

Now, perhaps you will say that there are no NULLs in your column - you really meant what you said, and every row has either 'Y' or 'N', there is no NULL.

That is OK, but that is known only after retrieving the data and inspecting it. Rather, if you want the index to be used as you expected, Oracle needs to know that there will be no NULL in that column WITHOUT seeing the data first. Which means: you need a CONSTRAINT on the table. If in fact the column is supposed to be NOT NULL, you can

```
ALTER TABLE TEMP_TABLE MODIFY (INDICATOR NOT NULL);
```

Alternatively,

```
SELECT INDICATOR 
FROM TEMP_TABLE
WHERE INDICATOR IS NOT NULL    --  ADDED! 
ORDER BY INDICATOR
```

will use the index (try it!); but if the column SHOULD be NOT NULL, then why not make that explicit with a constraint.